# Parts on "The Crypt Ghost"

Tags: part-identification

Please identify the curved pieces at the top frame of each segment of [The Crypt Ghost](https://ideas.lego.com/challenges/a06640fb-ebd7-4a38-aa6d-d25b77000ef1/application/393bb7a3-8314-476d-8e2a-0079402b98eb). (Are these dinosaur tails).  What about the multi-faceted pieces making up the tops and bottom of each grave?

Comment: Have you attempted to check Bricklink? Searching for "dinosaur tail" will produce short list with part you have already identified yourself. Another piece is easy to locate in "wedge" category, with the rest of similarly shaped elements.

Answer (score 5):

As far as I can tell, each arch half is made out of:

- [40379 Dinosaur tail end section](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=40379)
- [28870 Plant stem curved](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=28870)
- [4733 Brick 1x1 with studs in four sides](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=28870)
- [15208 Plate 1x2 with 3 teeth](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=28870)
- [49668 Plate 1x1 with tooth](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=28870)
- [37762 Cylinder 1x1.333](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=28870)
- 2x [43888 Brick 1x1x6 round with square base](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=28870)
- [35480 Plate 1x2 with round ends](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=28870)

There *might* be a [25269 1x1 round tile, quarter](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=25269) between the 1x2 plate and the plant stem, but it's a bit difficult to tell.

[image: LeoCAD diagram]

The piece used for the sarcophagi is [47757 Wedge 4x4 Pyramid Center](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=47757).

Comment: And of note: this is a render of a digital model, likely made in Stud.io. This means that these pieces might not exist in these particular colors in actual bricks.